How to remove the text "(End of deﬁnition for \foo. This function is documented on page ??.)" in the `macro` environment of l3doc class?
Just like the question, there will be a line of text "(End of deﬁnition for \foo. This function is documented on page ??.)". How to remove it?
\documentclass{l3doc}

\begin{document}

\begin{macro}{\foo}
  This is the usage of foo
\end{macro}

\end{document}



The macro environment is for documenting commands in the implementation, not in the main documentation. For that, use the function environment.
For commands that are not documented in the main documentation, you can pass the int (for "internal"; grays out command) or no-user-doc key.
\documentclass{l3doc}

\begin{document}

\begin{function}{\foo}
This is the usage of foo
\end{function}

\begin{macro}{\foo}
This is the implementation of foo
\end{macro}

\begin{macro}[int]{\blub}
This is the implementation of blub
\end{macro}

\begin{macro}[no-user-doc]{\gloo}
This is the implementation of gloo
\end{macro}

\end{document}



there should be more blub in the world!

@UlrikeFischer more blub and less blubbing?
